# distutils.spawn.find_executable and shutil.which can not find the file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find a file contained in our software with **python3**.

The problem is, an executable file which can be found in `the bash` environment with `find` command, can not be found in `zsh` environment with **python3**. This file is neither in the `$PATH` nor `os.environ["PATH"]`. I could only find it when I provide its absolute path as a parameter to `shutil` & `which`.

However, since the absolute path depends on the installation path of the software, it is different for each person. Therefore, I want to ask for a general method, which can find this excitable file with only its name provided. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `shutil.which` function uses `$PATH` variable to find executables. It works exactly as the bash `which` or `command -v`.

The `find` command uses a directory as input and searches recursively inside this directory.

To perform your search, you have to either append the directory in which your executable is in to your current PATH and then use `shutil.which` to locate it

```py
import os
import shutil
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/exe/location'
exec_location = shutil.which('myexe')
```

or use a function that works similarly to the `find` command :

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional

def find(name: str, location: Path) -> Optional[Path]:
    files = [ f for f in location.rglob('*') if f.is_file()]
    for f in files:
        if f.name == name:
            return f.resolve()
    
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. According to [PEP 632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/), distutils is deprecated since python 3.10, the answer here still works.